# Magento: SOLR: How to remove html tags from SOLR search keyword suggestion?

Tags: magento, solr, magento-1.4, solr4

I'm using SOLR search for Magento search, got some problem while searching. Please see the image.

[image]

In my product description i'm having some html tags. So When we are searching, html tags also coming in auto suggestion without special chars. Is there any possible to eliminate html tags here?

Comment: skips them from indexing ...add them in the stopfilter factory

Comment: Hi @AbhijitBashetti, i need to index description as well, but that needs to be without HTML tags. Could you please tell me whats stopfilter factory?

Comment: if you have read about the fieldtype you will know that it consists of tokenizser and filters. thise help you in tokinizing the texts. Filters examine a stream of tokens and keep them, transform or discard them...Stop filter factory discards common words....Can you share me the fieldtype used for the description? here is link fore more detail https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters

Comment: try this field type for description <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>         here in the stopwords.txt you need to add the html tags

Comment: check the answer by alexf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory), which will strip HTML tags:

> HTMLStripCharFilter strips HTML from the input stream and passes the result to either CharFilter or Tokenizer. Like other CharFilters, it's specified using a  tag, and must come before the **tokenizer**. An example:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

So, in the analyzer you used, just add this filter.

Comment: Thank you @alexf and Abhijit, it's working perfectly! :)